# Intercept touch on Camera button to control taking picture

Tags: iphone, uikit, uiview, camera

I would like to intercept the touch on the camera button to control exactly when I take the picture by using takePicture. I still want to use the standard UI control (so I would prefer not having my custom controls in the overlay).

Touch -> Button Clicked -> My code -> takePicture
(ie. Apple code for taking picture won't be called)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place a transparent button over standard controls and set it to Your custom function.